# Dumping Flash Memory Using Bus Pirate

Tags: dumping, flash

I'm planning on dumping and reading the flash memory of a Winbond W25Q128FV chip. I've done some research and plan on buying the following tools to achieve this:

- Bus Pirate 3.6a
- [Probe Cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01CRCSO2O)
- [SOIC8 Test Clip](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01KLT04PA)

I already have a soldering kit. Are these the right tools and are they sufficient to read the flash memory to my computer?

Also, I already have an Arduino Uno and a Raspberry Pi. Can either of those be used in place of a Bus Pirate?

Comment: NAND or NOR flash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're good to go. Yes the Raspberry has a SPI interface so you can connect the Winbond to it and use the "flashrom" to dump it. Attach the SOIC clip to the chip and connect the pins to the Raspberry Pi respective pins:
MISO
MOSI
Chip Select
Clock
Ground
Also the appropriate voltage Vcc 3.3 or 5. Pi can provide both .

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot, saved me $30 from buying a bus pirate!